# Karma+Jasmine: ajax call with real(not mocked) response

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner

I'd like getting real response from server when send XmlHttpRequest in karma env + Jasmine. Test case

```
it('get data from server', function (done) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', 'my_working_backPoint');
    request.onload = function (resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        done();
    };
    request.send();
});
```

But I get this:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout
       specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

I couldn't find any helpful answers. Please explain me how I could test real ajax call.

Comment: usually, when your running jasmine on karma, your server is in fact karma, therfore it can't reach your real backend.

Comment: But when I add angular module and * ngMidwayTester* module I can get real response from a server. So karma and jasmine can do that...